# NoMethodError Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to allow users to bookmark various coffee shops. I have successfully managed to allow users to favorite coffee shops, so was trying to follow the same steps, but I get a `NoMethodError` when trying to load `Coffeeshops#show`.

My code:

*user.rb*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :validatable,
  has_many :comments
  has_many :coffeeshops
  has_many :favorite_coffeeshops # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_coffeeshops, source: :coffeeshop
  has_many :bookmarked_coffeeshops # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :bookmarks, through: :bookmarked_coffeeshops, source: :coffeeshop
```

*coffeeshop.rb*

```
class Coffeeshop < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  belongs_to :roaster
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :favorite_coffeeshops# just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_coffeeshops, source: :user
  has_many :bookmarked_coffeeshops# just the 'relationships'
  has_many :bookmarked_by, through: :bookmarked_coffeeshops, source: :user
```

*bookmarked_coffeeshop.rb*

```
class BookmarkedCoffeeshop < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :coffeeshop
  belongs_to :user
end
```

*coffeeshop.show.html.erb*

`<%= link_to "Bookmark",   bookmarked_coffeeshops_path(@coffeeshop, type: "bookmarked"), method: :put %>`

*Migration*

```
class CreateBookmarkedCoffeeshops < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :bookmarked_coffeeshops do |t|
      t.integer :coffeeshop_id
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Error

```
undefined method `bookmarked_coffeeshop_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fadb9ccad30>:0x007fadc3232e90>
```

Comment: what's the exact error? and add relevant code on which line the error is thrown.

Comment: just added to the question

Comment: `bookmarked_coffeeshop_path` or `bookmarked_coffeeshops_path` i can't find `bookmarked_coffeeshop_path` in your `show` view. share your routes and `rake routes`

Comment: That was it I hadn't updated my routes.

Answer (score 0):

Schoolboy error - I hadn't updated my routes:

Adding:

```
resources :coffeeshops do
  put :bookmarked, on: :member
end
```

resolved the issue.